# Noob tries opening .ipynb

Tags: jupyter

Tried opening "Introduction to Derivatives.ipynb"  with jupyter_notebook.exe  - incorrect

Tried: Pip install nbopen

python -m nbopen.install_win

> nbopen: error: unrecognized arguments: to Derivatives.ipynb

tried windows file type association .ipynb isn't listed

Absolutely new, assume no prior knowledge

context https://github.com/nmarincic/machineintelligence

Comment: nbopen 01. Introduction to Derivatives.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`nbopen "01. Introduction to Derivatives.ipynb"`

The reason you are getting that error is because you didn't put your file name in quotes and your file name contains spaces. This results in your other words i.e. "to" and "Derivates.ipynb" being treated as arguments which are not expected by the `nbopen` handler

Comment: That worked thanks.  however now I'm seeing "404 : Not Found" in jupyter

Comment: I had to update the name, as your question gave a different file name to the one in the repository

Comment: Please let me know if the updated command works

Comment: I can launch the jupyter tree, but not the .ipynb file. 404 
Not sure how this works. Do I need to change a directory or..?  File name is congruent

Comment: Thats strange... mine's running fine. I do get 404 errors in the terminal, but that's becuase I only downloaded the ipynb file and not the images and other data that come with it

Comment: What's the manual way to do this? without nbopen

Comment: You can open it with VSCode or install Jupyter Notebooks